# how to handle concurrency in java servlets

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

In my doPost method of the servlet I need to access a file (shared resource ) and update the file . 
How do I cater to some 100 users using this at the same time ?

Regards,
Mithun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Create separate singleton class for file access.
- Use Read and WriteLock from java.util.concurent package to protect file access.
- Cache, so that you won't have to do file read if all you have to do is to return file content.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure a file is how you want to handle this? Protecting access to data by multiple concurrent users is most of what a modern database does.

Answer (score 1):

With high level of concurrency (for writes), synchronizing will cost you a lot of throughput.

Databases are more adequate to handle this, if possible in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of the java.util.concurrent packages added in Java 1.5.  Specifically a [BlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to queue up requests and handle them in a second pool of threads.